# Runtime error in OOP class (Corona)

Tags: coronasdk

New to Corona (coming from Actionscript) and trying to work through some OOP tutorials to create reusable modules for my app.  Currently working on a number picker, which seems to be working, but also throwing an error when I press the buttons.  Here's the code for the 'numberPicker.lua':

```
local numberPicker = {}
local numberPicker_mt = { __index = numberPicker }  -- metatable
widget = require "widget"

-------------------------------------------------
-- PUBLIC FUNCTIONS
-------------------------------------------------

function numberPicker.new() -- constructor

local newNP = display.newGroup()
local value = 0

local function dec()
    print("dec")
    if value > 0 then
        value = value - 1
        valueText.text = value
    end
end

local function inc()
    print("inc")
    if value < 100 then
        value = value + 1
        valueText.text = value
    end
end

decrement = widget.newButton{
    default="gfx/dec_normal.png",
    over="gfx/dec_press.png",
    width=58, height=58,
    onRelease = dec
}

valueText = display.newText(value, 70, 10, native.systemFont, 40)
valueText:setTextColor(0, 0, 0)

increment = widget.newButton{
    default="gfx/inc_normal.png",
    over="gfx/inc_press.png",
    width=58, height=58,
    onRelease = inc
}

increment.x = 140

newNP:insert(decrement.view)
newNP:insert(valueText)
newNP:insert(increment.view)
return setmetatable( newNP, numberPicker_mt )
end

return numberPicker
```

usage:

```
local numberPicker = require( "numberPicker" )
local lengthPicker = numberPicker.new()
scrollView:insert(lengthPicker)
```

When I press either button, I get the following error printing out twice:

```
Runtime error
attempt to call a nil value
stack traceback:
[C]: ?
```

Any clues anyone?
Thanks,
Emma.

Answer (score 0):

"scrollView" variable was not initialized.